# how to deal with special characters in html

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to insert special characters in my html page. For example text inside div can contain french alphabets. When I run my page there is obviously unfamiliar characters appear in my page

for example

```
®
```

renders something like this

```
Â®
```

But I can deal with registered character like above by using simple code but how about a foreign language, there can be any number of characters.

How can I implement html page so unfamiliar characher like Â®  won't appear again

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Would do the job.

---

Edit:

`UTF-8` does include letter like `®`, `©`, etc.

Comment: can you please add some words to explain the magic behind meta charset=utf-8?

Comment: Wait a moment...... Please accept the answer if you consider it useful / it can answer your question!

Comment: what about french alphanumerics

Comment: This is gross oversimplification. The `meta` tag helps only if the document is actually UTF-8 encoded *and* it does not conflict with HTTP headers. And the default charset is *not* ASCII; it depends on many things in a complicated manner.